# Jmeter Bean shell - Matching Correct Regex Array Value and saving group ID Number/Instance into a User Defined Variables

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I am new to Jmeter BeanShell Scripting/Java and currently facing issue using script below.

Using Regular Expression Extractor I am able to pull array of all possible values. For example: 10 date values, and the variable is defined as `${RegExValue_All}`  (Template: `$1$`; Match: `-1`)

Sample Value:

```
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
04/01/2017
05/01/2017
07/01/2017
07/01/2017
08/01/2017
10/01/2017
10/01/2017
```

Now I am trying to write a BeanShell script to match specific date and pull out its ordinal/index/iteration number and save it to a user defined variable `${Matched_Iteration_Value}` which is currently blank.
When I am using the code below, I am able to compare the correct required values as I have set for loop count as 10 but unable to save the ordinal/index/iteration number and getting various errors.

Also I want code to stop execution as soon as 1st match is obtained and its iteration number to be saved in a variable which I need to use in subsequent requests.

```
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException; 
import java.util.Date;
matches = (vars.get("RegExValue _All"));
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    if (vars.get("cPIGValueDate_All_" + i).equals("07/01/2017")) {
        log.info("Variable: cPIGValueDate_All_" + i + " is the Correct PIG");
        vars.putobject("Matched_Iteration_Value ",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script and explanation are a bit inconsistent, so I have to assume some things:

- That regex extractor is configured with Reference Name: `RegExValue`. So with Match: `-1`, when it finds more than 1 date, it will save them as variables with names `RegExValue_1`, `RegExValue_2`
- That you don't care about `RegExValue _All`, since you are retrieving it, but not using it anywhere, and it's not part of your question
- That you want to compare dates as dates (and not as strings), since you imported various date-related classes
- That your date is in format `dd/MM/yyyy`

So

1. First of all, the loop itself should be based on variable called `RegExValue_matchNr`, which is automatically created by JMeter when regex has more than one match. This is better than hard-coding loop to 20.
2. You can convert both, expected and actual dates from string to `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`.
3. Then you compare them as dates
4. And finally, save variable and exit the loop if dates are the same

Here's the code:

```
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

// 1.
int count = 0;
try {
    count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("RegExValue_matchNr"));
}
catch(Exception e) { }

// 2.
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date expectedDate = format.parse("07/01/2017");

for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    Date actualDate = null;
    try {
        actualDate = format.parse(vars.get("RegExValue_" + i));
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }

    // 3.
    if(actualDate != null && expectedDate.compareTo(actualDate) == 0) {
        log.info("Variable: RegExValue_" + i + " is the Correct PIG");
        // 4.
        vars.put("Matched_Iteration_Value", "" + i);
        return;
    }
}
```